# I cannot boot OpenSUSE after installing Linux Mint

Tags: linux, boot, grub, linux-mint, opensuse

My computer has OpenSUSE 11.3 installed and I added Linux Mint to it. Linux Mint runs without any issues, but when I choose OpenSUSE on the GRUB page where we choose the operational system, it does not boot (just a black screen) and the entire system restarts. I believe OpenSuse somehow does not match with GNU GRUB.

So, I want to be able to boot both Mint and OpenSUSE systems. How can I make this possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried to boot OpenSuSe directly? UEFI settings > Boot menu. Please test then [edit] the question to update it with the results.

Comment: I will try. Thanks for your comment!